# Newly installed ubuntu ( 22.04.3 LTS)can not open firefox, VS code

Tags: firefox, visual-studio-code

I installed this new ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. Have the following problems.

1. can not open firefox
   After typing firefox in the terminal,

Gtk-Message:12:30:46.240: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it

2. can not open vs code. I tried snap run code, etc.

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Open a Terminal. Run the command `firefox`. Copy the entire input and output. Paste it into your question above.

Comment: Similarly, the command to run VS Code is `code`, not snap run code

Comment: I tried "code", nothing pops out. Then google and find snap run code. nothing works either